# After $.post in .done() how do I use $(this)?

Tags: jquery, post, this

I am want this function to update text in a div on its completion of an ajax $.post call. Everything works just fine except that in the .done call $(this) is no longer looking at the element that it was listing to.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Add or Remove time from Time Off
        $(".timeChange").on("click", function(){
            var id              =   $(this).val();
            var timeCommand     =   $(this).attr("data-command"); 
            var currentTime     =   $(this).siblings('.timeHold').text();       

            $.post("humanResourceFunctions.php/",
                {
                    command         :   "modifyLeaveTime",
                    employee        :   id,
                    addSubtract     :   timeCommand,
                    time            :   currentTime
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $(this).siblings('.timeHold').text(data); 
                });
        });
```

The problem is in the the last operation, $(this).siblings('.timeHold').text(data);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to cache a reference to it.

```
$(".timeChange").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this); //cache it
```

Then later on..

```
.done(function(data) {
    $this.siblings('.timeHold').text(data); //note $this not $(this);
});
```